# Adding LaTeX in an edit and getting [Math Processor] errors

Tags: support, mathjax

I have been editing an answer to [Recurrence substitution method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179582/recurrence-substitution-method/179904#179904) in order to add LaTeX. However, I started getting [Math Processing Error] in the preview. I tried loading it in Firefox as well. I don't know if it would be easier for someone to find where I went wrong or to just start over again. I don't see where I've gone wrong and something as simple as "$n \log n$" is giving errors. If I messed something up, I'd appreciate it if anyone can point it out. I have a feeling it might just be on the client-side because I'm on a public computer and don't have any admin privileges.

**Edit:** Someone already accepted my edit and fixed the equation alignment which is what I was trying to do when I started encountering the errors. It appears that I failed to remove a "\end{align}" when I was trying to debug my LaTeX.

Answer (score 5):

In the [edit you submitted](https://math.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/8563) there was a missing `\begin{align}`, and that's where the $\color{#D00}{\textit{[Math Processing Error]}}$ came from.

I accepted your edit, added that missing piece, made some further formatting changes and now it looks fine.

Comment: Cool thanks. I was trying to figure out how to use `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}` when I started getting the errors. Then I wanted to get it back to a working state again, but missed removing the `\end{align}` somehow...*shrugs*

Comment: No problem. For a good overview over all the possibilities offered by the AMS-math package see [this documentation](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf). Most of these things work here with MathJax, but not all of them.